# Chinese for "rebirth"

Tags: translation

I am translating a text about a man who got divorced and after many days of desperation, he eventually starts accepting his situation and so he totally changes himself and starts a new life and a new way of being. This is described as "the Phoenix process", a rebirth, and he came to be a "new born" and a new man. How can I say all those things in few Chinese words? I thought about 重生 but I am not sure about its use. I was also wondering if there is a chengyu that can better explain it.

Comment: 涅槃 (nirvana) ought to be out of reincarnation, no more death - rebirth cycles :)

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 Thanks for correcting me! (OMG I've got it wrong for so many years...)

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 It seems I'm not the only one who gets it wrong, Guo Moruo must have misled many (See [凤凰涅槃](http://baike.baidu.com/link?url=Fu0LhyZdfbscbMUKKafR5XxkWdK75bRHKwmUy-c0xZGfwKMqXx-8KhpgD95ft7zN6xbw53wXh-EMtTuzZVKTeK)).

Comment: common saying：  **脱胎换骨**  （＂汉语熟语小词典＂：本来是道教用语。指修道要脱去凡胎，换掉凡骨。现多比喻改变认识或重新做人。［例］从欧洲访问回来后，他有一种  **脱胎换骨**  的感觉，感叹自己以前知道得太少了。

Answer (score 2):

**重新振作** ↓

[image]

**换了个人**↓

[image: ![enter image description here]

走出阴影↓

[image]

获得新生

[image]

重生一般

[image]

脱胎换骨(chengyu)

[image: ![enter image description here]

浴火重生 (chengyu)

[image]

凤凰涅磐 (chengyu)

[image]

羽化登仙(metamorphosis from human being to heavenly being)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Chinese, we even have a six-word phrase "鳳凰 (phoenix) 浴火 (bath in fire) 重生 (to reborn)", to refer to the mythology about phoenixes' reborn. "重生" means reborn, where 重 means "again" and 生 means "birth", so it can be used as a phrasal verb or a noun. 浴火重生 is also used frequently enough to be considered as something like an idiom/chengyu (although it doesn't have the long history like a chengyu).

Since you are translating, I recommend that you keep the original reference to the phoenix process. However, for future readers, if you are looking for another idiom that has a similar meaning, there is an old poem by 陸游, which can be used in a similar context: "山窮水盡疑無路，柳暗花明又一村", although it only implies the meaning of getting hope in the most (mentally) hopeless condition, but not literally (physically) the meaning of death/actual defeat.